# acceder a un localhost en Nodejs(Express) desde otro equipo

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, servidor

Estoy creando un API e Intento hacer peticiones desde otro equipo con la ip del equipo en donde esta ubicado el servidor pero no funciona, Necesito alguna configuración adicional para express o node para que acepte peticiones externas?.

Esto seria desde el servidor:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui ya intento acceder desde otro equipo y me arroja este error (Si esta en la misma red).[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y leas [ask] y agregues un [example]. "pero no funciona" no nos sirve de nada si no nos muestras el código o el error que obtienes.

Comment: Exactamente intento hacer este procedimiento pero al hacer una petición desde el otro equipo simplemente me arroja que no se puede accede a la pagina

Comment: Cuando el otro equipo hace la petición a tu API les sale textualmente "que no se puede acceder a la pagina"? Cuál es el status del error y el mensaje.

Comment: Ya adjunte el error que me aparece al hacer la solicitud en el post. :)

Comment: Solucionado, Era cuestión de desactivar el Firewall del lado del servidor.

Comment: Excelente entonces!